# Apply transformation to result of previous transformation on SVG path

Tags: svg, transform, snap.svg

If I apply a translation of (100, 0) to an SVG path, it shifts left by 100px. But if I first rotate the path, then the translation happens along a diagonal.

I understand why this happens -- the rotation has rotated the axes, thus making the translation along the x axis no longer horizontal. There are times, however, when this isn't desirable, when I'd like to apply a transformation to the result of a previous one rather than having it be affected by or affect those previous ones as well.

I know one solution is to put the transformed path in a group element, and then apply the second transformation to that group. But I'd like to avoid the need to create the group element if possible. In looking into this issue, I came across [Flatten.js](https://gist.github.com/timo22345/9413158), which "flattens" transformations. In other words, it modifies the original path of the element in order to make it equivalent to the transformation. However, this seems to only work on an entire `svg` element, rather than individual paths within it.

I'm currently working with [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/docs) in case that matters. I haven't been able to locate anything in the docs that seems relevant to this though.

To clarify what I'm trying to accomplish, take a look at these three examples:

[Square simply rotated](http://codepen.io/maxedison/pen/EjNjgm?editors=001)

[Rotate square, translate square](http://codepen.io/maxedison/pen/PqbqbV?editors=001)
Square rotated, then translated along the x axis by 50. But since the x axis has now been rotated, the square actually shifts diagonally down as well. This is the problem.

[Rotate Square, put in group, translate group](http://codepen.io/maxedison/pen/doOoNe?editors=001)
By putting the square into a group, and then applying the translation on the group element, the square shifts purely in a horizontal direction. This is what I want to achieve, but without having to put the square in a group.

Comment: If you don't want to use a group, then the main thing is getting the transforms in the order you require, try swapping the scale and translate around. There's a few bits at http://svg.dabbles.info/ which may help. I would probably put up a jsfiddle with an example and explain what you want to happen.

Comment: Updated with a few examples showing the issue and then the desired behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for Snap.svg was indeed in the docs: [Snap.path.map](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.map)

I'm using it like this:

```
    var new_shape = original_shape.paper.path(
        Snap.path.map(
            original_shape.realPath.toString(),
            original_shape.transform().localMatrix
        )
        .toString()
    );
```

This will create a clone of the original shape, but using a `path` element with all commands turned into `C`.

Put the above code into a function that takes a single argument -- the original shape:

```
function bakeMatrix(){
    var new_shape = original_shape.paper.path(
        Snap.path.map(
            original_shape.realPath.toString(),
            original_shape.transform().localMatrix
        )
        .toString()
    );
}
```

Or, better yet, create a Snap.svg plugin:

```
Element.prototype.bakeMatrix = function(replace){

    var shape = this.paper.path(
        Snap.path.map(
            this.realPath.toString(),
            this.transform().localMatrix
        )
        .toString()
    );

    if (replace) this.remove();
    return shape;
};
```

With that plugin, I can call simply `shape.bakeMatrix()` and get a clone of the shape, all transformations baked into the path. The additional parameter `replace` lets you decide whether the original shape should be discarded in the process, leaving just the transformation-baked clone.

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the order of your transform operations

```
matrix.translate(50,0).rotate(45, bounds.cx, bounds.cy);
```

Comment: Yes, that would work in a very specific case. But I'm looking for a broader solution. For example, what if I already have a rotated square but now I want to animate it to the right when a user clicks it? In that case, I don't have the luxury of picking the order of the transforms.

Comment: I guess the question is, why don't you always put the translation first ? You can still use the existing transformation, are you looking for something along these lines... http://jsfiddle.net/2pg41m9w/1/ the plugin will use the existing transform, but you can do what you want (probably the 'before' one).