# How to flatten a transformed svg path

Tags: d3.js, snap.svg, web-frontend

I am trying to use the Snap.Svg javascript library to create a new path string in svg from a previously transformed path. The new path string must have the old transformations baked into it when it is created. The problem is I am not sure what exactly the correct approach is.I have looked at this thread [Get the current matrix transformation of an SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434687/get-the-current-matrix-transformation-of-an-svg-element) but when I try to get the matrix to object to add to this method in snap.svg I get undefined. How can I get the transformation matrix object from the DOM node as shown in this example [Apply transformation to result of previous transformation on SVG path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426856/apply-transformation-to-result-of-previous-transformation-on-svg-path). The relevant method in the snap library I think is http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.map

My code:

```
   var result = d3.select(".line").node();
   console.log(result.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix);
```

The above returns null. How do I create/get the right transformation matrix object so I can use the Snap.path.map method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are using d3 or Snap, so answer may depend. If Snap, you could look at getting the matrix from

```
element.transform().localMatrix or 
element.transform().globalMatrix
```

and then using that matrix use

```
Snap.path.map( pathString, Matrix )
```

from http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.map to apply that transform

If you need to get the transform string, you can get that from

```
somepath.attr('d')
```